# Separate spring bean and hibernate bean

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am using spring and hibernate in my project. Here I have UserBean class in spring. It contains 5 properties:

```
   UserId, Password, AccountId, fromDate, toDate
```

I want to save only 3 fields `AccountId, fromdate and todate` in database.

Previously I was using single bean to save 5 fields in Database. Now I want to save 3 field in database.

Please guide me how I separate the hibernate and spring bean.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using annotation approach, you can use annotated POJO class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
class User {
 @Transient // do not consider userId for saving in database
 private int userId;
 @Transient
 private String password;
 private int accountId;
 private Date fromDate;
 private Date toDate;
 // getters and setters for above properties

}
```

If you are using xml based approach: check [this tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations) from jboss

Provide :

> User(pojo class which I have mentioned above),
>   UserController,
>   UserService,
>   UserDao(database operations done in this class)

Refer SpringSource documentation for more information and how to integrate spring and hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark certain properties as transient and Hibernate won't map them to database. See [more here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html)